# Problem of running development copy of WordPress on WebMatrix?

Tags: themes, customization

I am a newbie on WordPress and PHP but at a learning task to maintain running company website. I downloaded the copy of company website and database into local machine to try to setup a development environment. I installed WebMatrix bundle with WordPress, MySQL, PHP, IIS Express for simplicity. After I restored database to local MySQL and setup user name and password for data access from MySQL Workbench, I started a local session of website but I only saw blank page of the website instead of familiar theme from live company website. I have done a dozen google searches on the subject without breakthrough. I have checked following places though:
•   index.php in the root folder gets loaded, as my added echo statement could output information on blank page but the theme doesn’t show.
•   I can access localhost:xxx/wp-login.php page and type in user name and password to log in but then it will redirect me to live website not local page.
•   I checked database access is functioning and I updated wp-options table to use default theme not company theme to try to fix the issue with no success.
Can anyone shed some light for me to solve the puzzle so I could kick start on learning WordPress development from local machine?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the URL in database. WordPress use relative URL.

Check this [guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database) for migrating WordPress, how to make changes in database directly.

Thanks

Comment: I fixed the issue by myself but your link provides comprehensive detail, thank you Vee!